# JPA refresh entity

Tags: java, jpa

I have two tables in my database `USERS` and `ADDRESSES`, each user can have many addresses.

I have build entity classes with NetBeans wizard, and it create the classes well:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@XmlRootElement
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    // Some fields.......
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Collection<Address> addressCollection;

    public User() {
    }

    // Getters and Setters.......
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESSES")
@XmlRootElement
public class Address implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected AddressPK addressPK;
    // Some fields.......
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private User user;

    public Address() {
    }

    // Getters and Setters.......
}

@Embeddable
public class AddressPK implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private int userId;

    public AddressPK() {
    }
}
```

In the session I save the `User` instance of the current logged in user. But the `User`'s `addressCollection` never updates when I change the database like:

```
Address newAddr = new Address();
// Sets values to newAddr......
AddressFacade addrDao = new AddressFacade();
addrDao.create(newAddr); // Succeeded

LoginManager.getCurrentUser().getAddressCollection(); // Returns the old address list.
```

How can I refresh the current user's instance to get the correct `addressCollection`?

Comment: You should add the new created address to the User object because JPA doesn't do that automatically. In some part of your code you set the User to the Address to satisfy the relationship, so when this last one is properly saved you should add the new address to the user collection as well in order to keep *in-memory* consistency.

Comment: Since the User_id is part of the Address' primary key, you will probably want to look into orphan removal on the User's addressCollection as well.  That way you can simply dereference an Address from the collection, merge the user, and JPA will delete the address instance for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you have a bidirectional relationship, JPA requires that you keep both sides of the relationship in synch with each other.  This allows caching entities and other performance enhancements to be enabled by many providers.  In this case, when you set the USER_ID field, you should update the User's addressCollection that is affected by the change so that your object model stays in synch with what you are committing to the database.

An alternative is to force a refresh manually on the User instance.  This can be done with a em.refresh(user) call, or through provider specific options and query hints.  This is usually the least performant option though as it requires a database hit that isn't needed.

Comment: `em.refresh(user)` throws me an error `Cannot refresh unmanaged object`

Comment: You have to read the user from the context.  How are you obtaining the user?  If you are holding the user statically outside a context, it won't get updated unless you update it yourself.

Comment: The current user is stored in the session

Comment: But how can I easily maintenance those syncs? How can I sync `insert`, `update` or `delete` when I set the user in the address?

Comment: Nothing is ever easy.  If you want to cache the relationship in the entity, it has a cost, one of which is keeping the relationship in sync or it becomes less useful.  When ever you modify the Address, you will also need to modify the referencing User and add/remove the address as required, then merge the change.

Comment: And if I have more relationship with the user it will even much harder to maintaince.. I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: I solved found simple solution thanks to your comment. When I add the address like that: `LoginManager.getCurrentUser().getAddressCollection().add(addr)` and save the current user with `userFacade.edit(LoginManager.getCurrentUser()` it also sync and update the database correctly.